# Is there a better way to say "steal a disease"?

Tags: phrase-request

Is there a better way to say "steal a disease"? I feel like "steal a disease" doesn't make much sense, but there's really no better way of saying it. By "steal a disease" I mean transfer the disease from another person and into yourself, thereby curing the person you stole from. I really can't think of a better way to say this.

Comment: Infectious disease doesn't work that way, and I'm pretty sure it was never traditionally thought to work that way, so I'm not sure why you think there would be a word for it. Does such a term exist in another language? Is this a [Worldbuilding.SE] question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alleged process of *transferring the disease* in voodoo  practices. For example

> As soon as the doll is ‘animated’ visualize how you are solving the situation at that moment by making the disease separate from the patient and transfering it into the doll itself. (Source: [White Magic and Voodoo](https://www.white-magic-help.net/About_White_Magic/healing_spells.html)).

The word "stealing" is used in some fantasy games to describe a process of obtaining an supernatural ability by taking it from another person. For example

> Power Stealing is an ability possessed by certain supernatural and unnatural creatures to steal the powers of another, a process that is typically fatal... 
>   (Source: [Teen Wolf Wikia](https://teen-wolf-pack.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Stealing))

The idea of "stealing a disease" as you describe it is not something I have ever heard of, either in reality or in fantasy, so I'm not aware of any accepted term for it. But if the context makes it clear, i assume this term can be used.

Comment: Yes. And it could only properly be called *stealing* if the person who had the disease didn't give permission for it to be removed.